# Java Ceil Weirdness

Tags: java

Why does this output 0 instead of 1?

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.ceil(1/2)));
```

While this one correct outputs 1

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.ceil((double) 1/ (double) 2)));
```

Shouldn't `Math.ceil(double)` automatically type cast the 1/2 to double?

Comment: Ever do integer division? 1/2 = 0 using purely integer division though you may not be aware of this part of Mathematics.

Comment: If you _really_ want to blow your mind, try this: `System.out.println((int) (Math.ceil(1.0/2.0)));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.ceil` does, indeed, cast the integer to a double. But it only does so *after* the integer operation has been performed. This is the order of operations:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a / b; // now equals 0, because it's an integer operation.
double d = (double)c; // now it's a double - but equals 0.0.
double e = Math.ceil(d); // still 0.0.
```

You're thinking of `1/2` as a fraction, but it's not - it's an expression of two `int`s and an operator that has to be resolved before its value can be used in further expressions.

Answer (score 1):

*Explicit casting* always require `(datatype)` to be mentioned. Here `1` and `2` represents itself as `int` and to cast from `int` to `double` explicit casting will be introduced. Whenever casting is preformed from lower to higher datatypes explicit casting *should be imposed*. See example below;

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        int a = 100;
        long b = a; // Implicit cast, an int value always fits in a long
    }
}
```

An explicit casts looks like this:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        float a = 100.001f;
        int b = (int)a; // Explicit cast, the float could lose info
    }
}
```

Code Snippet: [Source](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0080__Type-Casting/Implicitandexplicitcasting.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing which happens when that line is executed, is that the division `1/2` is resolved. This happens without any consideration for the method-call to `Math.ceil` it is embedded in.

The literals `1` and `2` are integers. When you perform a division with only integers as arguments, an integer division is performed, which always rounds down. So the term gets resolved to the int value `0`. [`Math.ceil()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-) only accepts type `double`, but that's not a problem because Java can perform the conversion automatically and turn the int `0` to a double `0.0`.

To perform an explicit floating point division, have one or both of the parameters to the division be floating point literals:

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.ceil(1.0/2.0)));
```